# Sympy step by step solutions

Tags: python, sympy

Sympygamma offers step by step solutions for example for derivatives like this one: [http://www.sympygamma.com/input/?i=diff%28log%28x%29+%2B+2*x**2%2Cx%29](http://www.sympygamma.com/input/?i=diff%28log%28x%29%20%2B%202*x**2%2Cx%29)

How can I use this directly with sympy (e.g. in an ipython console or in a python script)?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359220/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-step-by-step-solution-in-sympy

Comment: Here I saw a similar question with the description of step-by-step info retrieval:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997931/sympy-step-by-step-solution-of-integrals