# Sympy step by step

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, algebra

im building a program for algebra stuff, right now im trying to get the step by step solution hence it is required for the process im trying to achieve.

i am able to get the final result but i was unable to find something about this in the documentation for sympy

```
from sympy import *


x = "3"
y = "-1"
z = "-4"

print(latex(sympify('(%s**%s)**%s' %(x,y,z))))
```

is there anyone that can point me in the right direction? or maybe offer an alternative path

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is

Comment: so to clarifiy, im trying to get the step by step:

(3**-1)**-4 the result is 81, but i also need the additional steps

(3**-1)**-4
    3**-1*-4
    3**4
    3*3*3*3
    81

Comment: You can use sympify with evaluate=False to get an unevaluated expression but then you'll need to work through each part manipulating the expression tree yourself to evaluate it step-by-step: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html

Comment: There’s this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359220/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-step-by-step-solution-in-sympy that proposes the use of binary trees with evaluation turned off.