# How to find out how SymPy solved an equation?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

When I solve an equation using SymPy, it would be nice to learn what it actually did to find the solutions.

The following is a simple test case for answers. We know it should be using the quadratic equation, or some equivalent approach.

```py
from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> solve(2*x**2 + 12*x + 12)
[-3 - sqrt(3), -3 + sqrt(3)]
```

Is some way of filtering through a record of the execution stack, or something else to extract what steps were useful to SymPy in solving a problem? I imagine some sort of tree-like search of steps is taken by SymPy, and a record of the stack calls would have to be pruned/simplified somehow.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359220/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-step-by-step-solution-in-sympy

Comment: You can always just read the code