# Can I get information from sympy which rules and substitutions it used to compute an indefinite Integral?

Tags: python, sympy

If I compute an indefinite integral with sympy an sympy is able to solve the task.
Is it possible to get the information which integration rules and variable substitutions it used to compute the indefinite integral?

Kind regards

Klaus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997931/sympy-step-by-step-solution-of-integrals

Comment: Thanks Oscar that is excatly what im looking for.